# iOS - programatically rejecting permission to contacts (after user has accepted)

Tags: ios, events, permissions, calendar, contacts

Is there a way to programatically reject/disable/disallow/reject permissions to access the calendar?

I'm using the following code to ask for / determine permissions:

```
//request access
[[MyCalendarUtil sharedManager] requestAccess:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

    /* This code will run when uses has made his/her choice */

    if(error)
    {
        // display error message here

        _calendarLabel.text = @"Calendar OFF";
    }
    else
    if(!granted)
    {
        // display access denied error message here

        _calendarLabel.text = @"Calendar OFF";
    }
    else
    {
        // access granted

        _calendarLabel.text = @"Calendar ON";
    }

}];
```

Can I disable the permission later on upon a user pressing a button ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way, its impossible. Take it granted. I will give 1 Million dollars even if you find a private API. :)

Its a privacy concern.

All you can do is, programmatically launching your application's preferences in the Settings App, and again its users wish to disable or enable the access.

Comment: tyvm for the swift response :D